Код не выполняется асинхронно
Моя проблема в том, что когда один пользователь отправляет фото и ждет ответ, и при этом второй пользователь через пару секунд тоже отправляет фото, то первый не получит ответ, пока не обработается фото второго пользователя.
@router.message(F.photo)
async def photo_processing(message: Message):
    task = asyncio.create_task(process_photo(message))
    await task


@measure_time
async def process_photo(message: Message):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    process_message = await message.answer(" Ищу номер на фото. . .", reply_markup=remove_keyboard)
    photo_path = await download_photo(message)

    # Находим номер на изображении
    crop_number = await loop.run_in_executor(None, detect, photo_path, message.from_user.username)
    if crop_number is not False:
        result_keras, result_easyocr = await read_number(crop_number)
        if result_keras is not False:
            markup = await create_inline_buttons(method="keras")
            await process_message.delete()
            await message.reply(f"Найден номер: <b>{result_keras}</b> \n\nВсе верно?", reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            # Если keras не определил, то выводим easyocr
            if result_easyocr is not False:
                markup = await create_inline_buttons(method="easyocr")
                await process_message.delete()
                await message.reply(f"Найден номер: <b>{result_easyocr}</b> \n\nВсе верно?", reply_markup=markup)
            else:
                await process_message.delete()
                await message.answer("⛔️ Не удалось определить номер.\n\n➡️ Попробуйте написать номер вручную.")
        
        if result_keras is not False or result_easyocr is not False:
            # Сохраняем результат
            saved_number[message.chat.id] = {
                "result_keras": result_keras,
                "result_easyocr": result_easyocr
            }

    else:
        await process_message.delete()
        await message.answer("⛔️ Не удалось найти номер на фото.\n\n➡️ Попробуйте написать номер вручную.")


А сам процесс который detect умеет параллельно в несколько запусков работать, он ничего сам не лочит (файлы/базу/ещё что-то)?

Вроде нет. Когда первому пользователю должен прийти ответ, выполняется await process_message.delete(), а await message.reply не приходит в телеграм. Приходит когда закончилась обработка всех фоток пользователей

Ну я бы попробовал для начала вообще убрать await process_message.delete(), починит ли это проблему? И по результатам думать дальше уже.

Не помогло, к сожалению

А, я неправильно понял. Я думал, что висело на удалении сообщения. Т.е. удаление сообщения срабатывало, а reply не срабатывал, на нём ожидание было, так?

Да, именно так.

EasyOCR и Keras в какой функций?

async def read_number(image_path: str):
results = await asyncio.gather(read_number_keras(image_path),
read_number_easyocr(image_path))
return results


А сами эти функции read_number... точно асинхронные до самого конца? Хотя вроде не на них стопорится, но лучше убедиться.
